# Is it possible short circuit evaluation happens in the following case

Tags: java

```
public class JavaApplication11 {

    static boolean fun() {
        System.out.println("fun");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean status = false;
        status = status & fun();
        status = fun() & status;
    }
}
```

Will Java thought, since `status` is already false, it will not executed `fun` method? I tested, in both case, `fun` will be executed. But, is it guarantee across Java spec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short circuit evaluation does not happen here because you are using the *bitwise* and operation (`&`) instead of the *logical* and operation (`&&`).

Answer (score 1):

double `&` is for short circuit operations. Use

```
status = status && fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator is guaranteed to be short-circuiting.
The `&` operator is guaranteed not to.